# Program won't compile completely without giving an error of parsing

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm writing this code to implement a stack as a linked list but I keep getting an error when I compile this part of the code and can't figure out why

I definitely know that it shouldn't be giving me this error since there are enough brackets and none of them are out of place I hope

The Error:

```
C:\Users\Michelle\Desktop\ITB\Semester 5\Data Structures & Algorithms\Assignment\ListReference.java:108: error: reached end of file while parsing
}
 ^
1 error
```

My Code:

```
public class ListReference implements StackInterface {

    private Node top;
    //private Object item;
    private int NumItems;

    public ListReference() {
        NumItems = 0;
        top = new Node(null);
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return NumItems == 0;
    }

    public int size() {
        return NumItems;
    }

    /*public Node find(int index) {
        Node curr = tail;

        for(int skip = 1; skip < index; skip++) {
            curr.getNext();
        }

        return curr;
    }*/

    public Object get(int index) {
        if(index <= 0)
            return null;

        Node ListReference = top.getNext();

        for(int i=1; i < index; i++) {
            if (ListReference.getNext() == null)
                return null;

            ListReference = ListReference.getData();
        }
    }

    public void add(int index, Object item) {
        Node ListReferenceTemp = new Node(item);
        Node ListRefCurr = top;

        while(ListRefCurr.getNext() != null) {
            ListRefCurr = ListRefCurr.getNext();
        }

        ListRefCurr.setNext(ListReferenceTemp);
        NumItems++;
    }

    public void add(Object data) {
        Node ListReferenceTemp = new Node(item);
        Node ListRefernce = top;

        for(int i=1; i < index &&  ListReference.getNext() != null; i++) {
            ListReference = ListReference.getNext();
        }

        ListReferenceTemp.setNext(ListReference.getNext());
        ListReference.setNext(ListReferenceTemp);
        NumItems++;
    }

    // removes the element at the specified position in this list.
    public boolean remove(int index) {
        // if the index is out of range, exit
        if (index < 1 || index > size())
            return false;

        Node ListRefCurr = top;
        for (int i = 1; i < index; i++) {
            if (ListRefCurr.getNext() == null) {
                return false;
            }

            ListRefCurr = ListRefCurr.getNext();
        }

        ListRefCurr.setNext(ListRefCurr.getNext().getNext());
        NumItems--; // decrement the number of elements variable
        return true;
    }

    public String toString() {
        Node ListReference = top.getNext();
        String output = "";

        while (ListREference != null) {
            output += "[" + ListRefCurr.getData().toString() + "]";
            ListRefCurr = ListRefCurr.getNext();
        }

        return output;
    }
```

Comment: Your file ends with the closing brace of a *method* - you need another closing brace to close the *class* declaration. Note that this is a great example of where it would have made sense to try to simplify your code further and further until you reached a *minimal* example... you've posted over 100 lines of code, *very* little of which has anything to do with your actual problem.

Comment: Just add one } to the end of the file.

Comment: An IDE would also be of use here, as the majority of them show you some form of visual bracket matching so that you can see which bracket you're closing.

Comment: Also: "I definitely know that it shouldn't be giving me this error since there are enough brackets" - not in what you posted. Finding a compiler error is a *very* rare occurrence... you should always assume that it's your code which is broken, not the compiler.

Comment: I guess his class is fine but he forgot one "}" when copy/paste. The problem is the "Object get()" function, there is no "return" at the end.

Comment: As JonK said, an IDE will make your Java-coding experience much much nicer. The most popular one is the Eclipse IDE For Java Developers, here: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/